# I want to change value of XML tag in java

Tags: java, xml

Here is my XML:

```
<Connections>
  <Connection>
    <userName>infadf</userName>
    <password>tcslkvcvo@123</password>
    <schemaName>dbo</schemaName>
    <status>OLD</status>
    <portNum>600687</portNum>
    <aliasName>first</aliasName>
  </Connection>
</Connections>
```

I want to change value of tag "status" to "NEW".

Below is my java code:

```
DocumentBuilderFactory dbFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
            DocumentBuilder dBuilder = null;

                try 
                {
                    dBuilder = dbFactory.newDocumentBuilder();
                } catch (ParserConfigurationException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

            if(new File(path).exists())
            {
                Document doc = null;
                try {
                    doc = dBuilder.parse(path);
                } catch (SAXException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

            doc.getDocumentElement().normalize();
            NodeList nList = doc.getElementsByTagName("Connection");

            for (int temp = 0; temp < nList.getLength(); temp++) 
            {

                    Node nNode = nList.item(temp);
                    Element eElement = (Element) nNode; 
                    if (nNode.getNodeType() == Node.ELEMENT_NODE) 
                    {

                    }

                    if(eElement.getElementsByTagName("status").item(0).getTextContent().equalsIgnoreCase("OLD"))
                    {
                        eElement.getElementsByTagName("status").item(0).setTextContent("NEW");
                    }
            }

        }
```

The value of status tag is not getting changed in XML.
Please help.

Comment: And after you changed it - did you save it back to file ?

Comment: You are chaining its in-memory value, you will need to write the value out to the file to achieve what you want.

Comment: Yes i have saved the XML file again after writing but then too the value of tag is not changed

Answer (score 0):

Try this..

`if("status".equalsIgnoreCase((nNode.getNodeName()))) { nNode.setTextContent("2000000"); }`

Answer (score 0):

The piece of code which you have written is working.

May be the way you are checking weather its working or not is wrong.
I have gone through [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4412848/xml-node-to-string-in-java) for checking the update on the XML what you have done.

You still have any doubts on what you did? I cannot post images because of my reputation score otherwise I would have shown the output what I got from eclipse.

Comment: Please check [this](http://i1252.photobucket.com/albums/hh567/jkiran809/StackOverFlow_JavaXML_zpsa346a017.png)