# How do i fix Document: null error on GML-Response

Tags: java, jdom

I have to convert a GML-Server Response to a GPX-File with jdom in Java
So far the Get-Feature-Request i send to the server is correct and gives me a GML-File as response, but when i want to print the file it says [#document: null]

The output on console:

url https://www.geoportal-amt-beetzsee.de/isk/beet_radwanderwege?service=WFS&version=1.0.0&REQUEST=GetFeature&typename=Riewend-Burgwall-Wanderweg

**[#document: null]**

```
try {
    //zu Funktionstestzwecken - löschen wenn nicht mehr benötigt
    String typename = gui.ConverterDialog.tfconverter.getText();
    String urlString = gui.UrlDialog.txturlinput.getText() + "?service=WFS&version=1.0.0&REQUEST=GetFeature&typename=" + typename;

    //entfernen wenn nicht mehr benötigt
    System.out.println("url "+ urlString);
    URL url = new URL(urlString);

    DocumentBuilderFactory dbf = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
    DocumentBuilder db = dbf.newDocumentBuilder();
    Document doc = db.parse(url.openStream());
    //doc.getDocumentElement().normalize();

    //entfernen wenn nicht mehr benötigt
    //doc null ???
    System.out.println(doc);

} catch(Exception e) {
    String errorMessage = "An error occured:" + e;
    System.err.println(errorMessage);
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When the line

```
System.out.println(doc);
```

runs, it calls the `toString()` method of the document `doc` and prints out that.  The `toString()` method of the document doesn't serialize the XML document to a string; instead it just prints the node name and its value.  The name of the document node is `#document`, and document nodes don't have values, so `null` gets printed instead.

I tried running your XML parsing code on a test XML document and it also printed out `[#document: null]`.

It might look like your XML parsing has failed and left you with an empty document, but I don't believe that to be the case.  Your code is quite probably working correctly.

If you want to serialize an XML document to a string, see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4412848/xml-node-to-string-in-java).

Comment: Thanks for the answer and the suggestion, its good to know that the code so far is correct.

Answer (score 0):

This Code solved the issue:

```
    //...
    DocumentBuilderFactory dbf = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
    DocumentBuilder db = dbf.newDocumentBuilder();
    Document doc = db.parse(url.openStream());
    doc.getDocumentElement().normalize();
    Transformer transformer = TransformerFactory.newInstance().newTransformer();
    transformer.setOutputProperty(OutputKeys.INDENT, "yes");


    StreamResult result = new StreamResult(new StringWriter());
    DOMSource source = new DOMSource(doc);
    transformer.transform(source, result);

    String xmlString = result.getWriter().toString();
    System.out.println(xmlString);
```